# Details for adding search service account to server local policies

Tags: search

We're getting lots of crawl errors for: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020)

Microsoft have recommended that on the Search and Web Front End servers:
1/ add the search service account explicitly to the local policies
2/ Configure the antivirus software to exclude folders/subfolders from antivirus scanning as per: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/952167/certain-folders-may-have-to-be-excluded-from-antivirus-scanning-when-y)

I'm trying to get details of the task:
add the search service account explicitly to the local policies

These are 2012 servers

Can anyone advise/refer?
Thanks
Bill

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard about the first suggestion.

Please try to configure antivirus and then abserve if the error persists.

Comment: Thanks engineerer. That is the plan for now.
I find it surprising that it's a common error message but so little explanation of it/the causes
Cheers Bill